# Short way to add dictionary item to a set only when its string value isn't empty?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I currently have this piece of code:

```
name_set = set()
reader = [{'name':'value1'}, {'name':''}, {'name':'value2'}]
for row in reader:
    name = row.get('name', None)
    if name:
        name_set.add(name)
print(name_set)
```

In the real code the `reader` is a DictReader, but I use a list with dicts to represent this.

Note that the `if name:` will check for:

- Empty string present in the Dictionary (thus `""`)
- Not whenever the key does not exist in the Dictionary

Although, I think this code is easy readable, but I'm wondering if there is a shorter way as this code is 6 lines to simply extract values from `dict`s and save these in a `set`.

Comment: This is honestly not bad. I could nitpick a bit here and there but it probably wouldn't make the code much shorter.

Comment: You can use set comprehension: `name_set = {row['name'] for row in reader if row.get('name', None)}`

Comment: smart! Thankyou! @zwer

Comment: Feel free to check out our sister site [CodeReview.se]. They are a great community where you can post working code to get feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is fine.

But since you asked for a "short" way, you could just use set comprehensions/arithmetic:

```
>>> reader = [{'name':'value1'}, {'name':''}, {'name':'value2'}]
>>> {d['name'] for d in reader} - {''}
{'value1', 'value2'}
```

Comment: This will raise a KeyError if 'name' is not in the dictionary. (The original code checks for this.) Perhaps `{d.get('name') for d in reader} - {'', None}`?

Comment: @Will  Yes.  In the absence of any other context, I prefer the `KeyError` unhandled.